# Glide not loading image properly

Tags: java, android, image, kotlin, android-glide

[image]

Here the image is not completely loaded. I don't know why. Somehow half placeholder & somehow half image. Sometimes it loads without any issue.

I am using

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Here is my code

```
val headerView = nav_view.getHeaderView(0)
Glide.with(act).load(userdata.image).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_male).thumbnail(0.2f).into(headerView.imgNavDp)
```

XML

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim_5"
            android:id="@+id/imgNavDp"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dim_76"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dim_76"
            android:elevation="@dimen/dim_10"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
```

Comment: check your image url in browser first its okay?

Comment: it is 100% correct, if not then how it can load some times

Comment: okay put some static url, or try with diff url, or change version

Comment: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a work around to handle loading error issues in Glide

**import** this, and keep the **compile sdk version to 27**

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
```

then Use this code

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(userdata.image)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_male)
        .error(R.drawable.imagenotfound)
        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                // log exception
                Log.e("TAG", handle error case", e);
                return false; 
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                 Log.e("TAG", handle success case here", e);
                return false;
            }
        })
        .into(headerView.imgNavDp);
```

and **remove** this from `xml`

```
 app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```